# Create a user from index page of user - using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise for authentication and user creation but one of my requirement is that any logged in user can create another user also. Whether it is right approach to override devise controller for user and create a view or is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate new User scaffold, if u do not have it.

```
rails g scaffold users email
```

In `users_controller.rb` file add this

```
class UsersController < AdminController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
end
```

So on If user not signed in, then it will return back to sign_in page.

---

Do not forget to delete MIGRATION file, after scaffolding. All you need is generate view and controller. Then run `rake db:migrate` just for make sure. It not supposed to give you an error anyway.

Comment: only need to generate controller no need to scaffold in scaffold model also create and there is also one devise use exist in application

Comment: if generate a controller only then he is going to write all view/users pages and all CRUD operations.

Comment: ya but why generating user Model ?

Comment: I think, He wants todo. When other signed_in user creates a new user. and  The new user has able to sign in too.